# how to avoid shinyapp reloading

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I currently try to set up a Shiny page with the `fileInput` and users are able to download after some simple manipulation of their own file.

Uploading large file sometimes takes more than one minute so page reload (*disconnect from the server*) would abrogate the file processing before users are able to download.

I put `session$allowReconnect(TRUE)` but re-connect won't keep the file of course. Does anyone have a solution to that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the user being disconnected isn't a regular occurrence. If it is, you may have a bug in the code that generates the file for download.

You could write the file to disk as a first step and then poll whether the file exists to have the user download it. This may require each user has their own results folder where it gets saved or each file has a unique ID associated with the user to avoid cross contamination between users though, for example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I then found that disconnection occurs whenever the server starts processing file larger about 40Mb. And it seems that there's no problem in file uploading, and files with smaller sizes (e.g. 20Mb) all work well (processing and download). I am wondering it's a limitation due to the free plan.

Comment: i know there is a Max File Size for uploading but this is set (and can be changed in a shiny server config file). Perhaps this is what you're looking for. I think the default is 5MB